# How to get the top "n" most frequently used words from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists. Each list includes words. Some words are common to both lists, some are not. I want to output only 20 most frequently common words but my code shows all common words. I want to limit the range to 20. I'm not allowed to use COUNTER.

```
def countwords(lst):
    dct = {}
    for word in lst:
        dct[word] = dct.get(word, 0) + 1
    return dct


count1 = countwords(finallist1)
count2 = countwords(finallist2)

words1 = set(count1.keys())
words2 = set(count2.keys())

common_words = words1.intersection(words2)
for i,w in enumerate (common_words,1):
    print(f"{i}\t{w}\t{count1[w]}\t{count2[w]}\t{count1[w] + count2[w]}")
```

Expected output:

```
common   f1 f2 sum 
1 program 5 10 15 
2 python  2  4  6 
.
.
until 20
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to achieve this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> word_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "two", "three", "four", "three", "four", "four"]

>>> Counter(word_list).most_common(2)
[('four', 4), ('three', 3)]
```

From the [`Counter().most_common()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) :

> **Return a list of the "n" most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least**. If "n" is omitted or None, most_common() returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are ordered in the order first encountered

---

Here's an **alternative** to achieve the same **without importing any module**:

```
# Step 1: Create Counter dictionary holding frequency. 
#         Similar to: `collections.Counter()` 
my_counter = {}
for word in word_list:
    my_counter[word] = my_counter.get(word, 0) + 1

# where `my_counter` will hold:
# {'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
#-------------

# Step 2: Get sorted list holding word & frequency in descending order.
#         Similar to: `Counter.most_common()`
sorted_frequency = sorted(my_counter.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# where `sorted_frequency` will hold:
# [('four', 4), ('three', 3), ('two', 2), ('one', 1)]
#-------------

# Step 3: Get top two words by slicing the ordered list from Step 2.
#         Similar to: `.most_common(2)`
top_two = sorted_frequency[:2]

# where `top_two` will hold:
# [('four', 4), ('three', 3)]
```

Please refer the comments in above code snippet for the step by step explanation.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use Counter.Sorry.

Comment: @elomelo check the edit. another one without importing any module

Comment: @elomelo if this answer helped you, you can upvote it by clicking up arrow on the left. It will help me with 10 additional reputation gain. You can also mark the answer as accepted (best answer) by clicking tick icon on the left of answer